# Video freezing issue ExoPlayer on some devices

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer

- The issue: Video freeze for seconds (between 10 to 15 seconds) before starting the video.
- When to produce: most times it's appeared (even on the same video, it's not happened)
- videos size: 1820*1020 (even choosing videos with different sizes cause the same issue)
- Screen size: 1920*1020
- Player: I am using Exo player 2.8.11
- Log: when the video is freezing, the log shows about 10k line of log that telling stream list full wait, check below:

  2020-07-27 18:15:27.078 342-13467/? E/ROCKCHIP_VIDEO_DEC: Rkvpu_SendInputData(495): stream list full wait

Comment: Did you get any progress with this? i have just switched from mediaplayer to exoplayer and my logcat is flodded with the same message. All videos continue playing though (i've got 4 running at the same time).